# Save entire QGraphicScene with sub elements to a file

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a customised QGraphicScene with some QGraphicsItem QGraphicsLine etc on it. Same way showed in diagramscene example of qt. Is there a way I can save it to a file and later when needed open and re-use or modify it?
Working on PyQt4 but answers with qt4 relevance (c++ instead of python) are also welcome.

This is essentially save and recreate.

```
    ##want to save the scene
    elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_S and modifier == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
        #saving all the items in the current scene 
        self.arrowItemVec=[]
        self.allItems=self.scene.items()
        #for arrow we need the start and end item to recreate
        #for now only saving the names
        for item in self.allItems:
            if 'Arrow'==item.__class__.__name__:
                self.arrowItemVec.append([item.startItem().name,item.endItem().name])
    elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_L and modifier == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
        #recreating all the saved items
        #if the scene is cleared before creating new items. we 
        #loose the old item positions
        #essentially we need to save the complete scene

        #detect what item it was and then recreate it 
        newItemVec=[]
        for item in self.allItems:
            if 'DiagramItem'==item.__class__.__name__:
                newItem=DiagramItem(diagramType=item.diagramType,contextMenu=None)
                newItem.name=item.name
                newItem.signaller.showChild.connect(self.showChildGraph)
                newItemVec.append(newItem)
                newItem.setPos(item.pos().x()+10,item.pos().y()+10)               
            #else:
                #print(item.__class__.__name__)
        count=0
        for item in self.allItems:
            if 'Arrow'==item.__class__.__name__:
                for newItem in newItemVec:
                    if newItem.name==self.arrowItemVec[count][0]:
                        startItem=newItem
                    if newItem.name==self.arrowItemVec[count][1]:
                        endItem=newItem
                count+=1
                newArrow=Arrow(startItem,endItem)
                newArrow.setZValue(1000)
                newItemVec.append(newArrow)
        self.scene.clear()
        self.scene.addGrid()
        for item in newItemVec:
            self.scene.addItem(item)
```

Comment: Hi, you need to tell us what you've tried so far. Pasting the code that you've written is a good start.

Comment: @Yann4 I extended the diagramscene example of in pyqt demo

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way of saving a QGraphicsItem or derived class to a file.

What you need to do is iterate through each item and save its properties, which you can then read back in and recreate the scene.

Comment: can you see the code and tell me what more can I do?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know Python, but the concepts are the same as C++ with Qt. Of-course, position, orientation and scale are important to restore an item in the scene, after that I suggest saving and reloading a scene of items and see if anything is different, to check if you've missed anything.